# How to get values from Open office spreadsheet?

Tags: java, openoffice.org

How to get the values from spread sheet? I would like to read from using java language?

Answer (score 1):

OpenOffice documents are Zipped XML files.  Copy one, rename it to .zip, open it and look into the XML & you'll see the data in the cells.

To access one using Java code:

- Use [ZipInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) to get access to the XML.
- Then use any of the slew of XML APIs in J2SE (DOM, Sax etc.) to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

Use OpenOffice.org [UNO](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide) API.