# How to read the openoffice .sxc spreadsheet?

Tags: java, openoffice-base

I need to to read the data in the openoffice .sxc spreadsheet. I have seen the openoffice java SDK to operation the openoffice. Indeed, it is difficult for me to understand. I need to loop the sxc spradsheet and read the cells. Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Quick googling spit out this: http://java67.blogspot.de/2014/09/how-to-read-write-xlsx-file-in-java-apache-poi-example.html . Haven't tried it myself but looks like a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the OpenOffice UNO API for Java.  You  can get it from http://api.openoffice.org/

Looks like the best places to start reading are the [Developer's Guide](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide) , and the samples in  [Java](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/Java)

But there is another solution ;

[How to get values from Open office spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556485/how-to-get-values-from-open-office-spreadsheet)

Comment: can you give one example? Thank you!

Comment: I saw the example in the openoffice Java SDK, On the page 30 in the document you provide, the example is how to create an empty spreadsheet and insert data. my requirement is to read an openoffice sxc file and get the data. I think there is not many differences between the inserting and reading.  However, could you please give some methods.